# exampleblock and equations (Beamer)

Tags: beamer, equations

I got an error with the `exampleblock` environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Title}
\begin{exampleblock}
\[
t = \frac{1}{\lambda}\mbox{ln}\left(\frac{N(t)-D(t)}{N(t)}\right)
\]
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Latex says "exempleblock environment undefined." Where is the problem?

Comment: Check your spelling: it's `exampleblock` and it's missing a second argument: it wants to be invoked as `\begin{exampleblock}{title}`. See beamer guide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All `block`s environments need a title, so the syntax

```
\begin{exempleblock}
stuff
\end{exempleblock}
```

is wrong. To fix the problem use:

```
\begin{exempleblock}{Title}
stuff
\end{exempleblock}
```

or at least:

```
\begin{exempleblock}{}
stuff
\end{exempleblock}
```

So your example is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern} % to remove warnings of size substitution
\usetheme{PaloAlto}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{My equation}
\begin{exampleblock}{title}
\[
t = \frac{1}{\lambda}\mbox{ln}\left(\frac{N(t)-D(t)}{N(t)}\right)
\]
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

#### Disclaimer

I'm sure we already had a similar question, but I cannot find it now.