# Too much space in exampleblock in Beamer

Tags: beamer

When I use the `\exampleblock` environment in Beamer, there is a lot of empty space between the title of the box and the content of the box.  How can I remove this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{GSA on the Black-Scholes Model}
  \begin{exampleblock}{Black-Scholes}
    \begin{align*}
      \text{Call: } C & = S\mathcal{N}(d_1) - K\mathrm{e}^{-r\tau} \mathcal{N}(d_2), \\
      \text{Put: } P & = -S\mathcal{N}(-d_1) + K\mathrm{e}^{-r\tau} \mathcal{N}(-d_2), \\
      d_1 = d_2 + \sigma \sqrt\tau & = \frac{\log(S/K) + (r + \sigma^2 / 2)\tau}{\sigma \sqrt \tau}.
    \end{align*}
  \end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Results in:
[image: Output]

I would like the top line of the math to be close to the title, as in the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94468/exemple-block-and-equations-beamer).

Comment: Is this a duplicate? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47400/remove-vertical-space-around-align

Comment: Switching to `aligned` improves the spacing:   `\begin{exampleblock}{Black-Scholes}
    \[
    \begin{aligned}
      \text{Call: } C & = S\mathcal{N}(d_1) - K\mathrm{e}^{-r\tau} \mathcal{N}(d_2), \\
      \text{Put: } P & = -S\mathcal{N}(-d_1) + K\mathrm{e}^{-r\tau} \mathcal{N}(-d_2), \\
      d_1 = d_2 + \sigma \sqrt\tau & = \frac{\log(S/K) + (r + \sigma^2 / 2)\tau}{\sigma \sqrt \tau}.
    \end{aligned}
    \]\end{exampleblock}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, using `aligned` is good. Rather than centered display `\[ ... \]` you can use `\hfil $ ... $` to have less vertical space. It's also possible to change the values of the `displayskips` as mentioned in the link above [tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47400/remove-vertical-space-around-align](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47400/remove-vertical-space-around-align)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\vspace` before the `align`. Try this:

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{GSA on the Black-Scholes Model}
  \begin{exampleblock}{Black-Scholes}
    \vspace{-.8cm}
    \begin{align*}
      \text{Call: } C & = S\mathcal{N}(d_1) - K\mathrm{e}^{-r\tau} \mathcal{N}(d_2), \\
      \text{Put: } P & = -S\mathcal{N}(-d_1) + K\mathrm{e}^{-r\tau} \mathcal{N}(-d_2), \\
      d_1 = d_2 + \sigma \sqrt\tau & = \frac{\log(S/K) + (r + \sigma^2 / 2)\tau}{\sigma \sqrt \tau}.
    \end{align*}
  \end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}
```